# Cypher count matches for multiple matches

Tags: cypher

I have the following simple database: `Person` nodes with the attribute `name` are connected to each other via the relationship `follows`. So e.g.
`(n:Person {name: "a1"})-[:follows]->(m:Person {name: "a2"})`.

I now have a list of people and I want to know which people are followed most often by the people in the list.

E.g. for the list `[name:"a1", name:"a2", name:"a3"]` I get:

- a1 follows b1, b2, b3
- a2 follows b2, b3
- a3 follows b3

I would like the result:

- b3: 3,
- b2: 2,
- b1: 1

Unfortunately, I have no idea how I could implement that. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try this:

1. `UNWIND` the list of names.
2. FETCH users have the names present in the list and the people they follow.
3. For each distinct person being followed, calculate the count.

Something like this, given your list of names is `["a1","a2","a3"]`:

```
UNWIND ["a1","a2","a3"] AS names
MATCH (p:Person) WHERE p.name = names
OPTIONAL MATCH (p)-[:follows]->(m:Person)
WITH m, count(p) AS followersCount
RETURN m, followersCount
```